# Checking if a string is filled or not

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to check for an internet connection. In this check I'm wanting to see two things:

1) is there a network connection

2) is there an endpoint (url) link

Should there be an internet connection, but no endpoint destination, it should do one thing, but if there is no internet connection and if it has an endpoint link or not, it should do something else.

I've got the first part working, I'm just having issue with checking if my string is filled or not when there isn't a connection. This is my code so far:

```
if(TestInternetConnection.connectionTrue.Equals(true) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(endPoint1))
{
    Debug.Log("connection is true");
}

if(TestInternetConnection.connectionFalse.Equals(false) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(endPoint1) || endPoint1 != null)
{
    Debug.Log("connection is false");
}
```

This should be returning `connection is true` but its constantly return back `connection is false`. How can I get it properly check my string?

Comment: Your second condition is (probably) always true. Try to split it in multiple bool variables and see in debug their value...

Comment: try to change `...connectionFalse.Equals(false)` to `connectionFalse.Equals(true)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put () to give priority in your code while checking second line

```
if(TestInternetConnection.connectionTrue.Equals(true) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(endPoint1))
{
    Debug.Log("connection is true");
}

if(TestInternetConnection.connectionFalse.Equals(false) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endPoint1) || endPoint1 != null))
{
    Debug.Log("connection is false");
}
```

So firstly will be checked (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endPoint1) || endPoint1 != null)) and then checked other parts.

Comment: -1 I don't know what OP is trying to check but here second condition is **always true**: `endPoint` is `null` or empty is matched by first part and not `null` is matched by second one. It's as you wrote `A || !A`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
if(TestInternetConnection.connectionTrue.Equals(true) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(endPoint1))
{
    Debug.Log("connection is true");
}
else if(TestInternetConnection.connectionFalse.Equals(false) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endPoint1) || endPoint1 != null))
{
    Debug.Log("connection is false");
}
```

Comment: Just did, and it's the same result as my question (always returns back connection is false)

Comment: try to put the last two condition in same bracket.. as shown in code above.

Comment: -1 I don't know what OP is trying to check but here second condition is **always true**: `endPoint` is `null` or empty is matched by first part and not `null` is matched by second one. It's as you wrote `A || !A`.